# ubuntu 18_04 LTS netplan

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled} network:

network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses:
            - 10.10.6.50/24
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 10.10.6.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 8.8.4.4
                search: []
        enp3s2:
            dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      interfaces:
        - enp3s2
            addresses:
            - 10.10.7.50/24
    version: 2
```

when i run `sudo netplan apply` 
gives below error

> Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml line 17 column 2: did
>   not find expected key

All I wanted is to create a working bridged network but stuck with yaml, can someone help..

Comment: Line 17 of this file looks fine. Are you sure that this is `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1) "version: 2" must be idented on same level of "ethernets". I used to add it as the first line after network:

2) add "dhcp6: false" on both configs (eno1 and br0)